# wagtail StreamField block name translation issue

Tags: translation, wagtail

What I found in docs is the following:

> The parameter to StreamField is a list of (**name**, block_type) tuples. ‘name’ is used to identify the block type within templates and the internal JSON representation (and should **follow standard Python conventions for variable names: lower-case and underscores, no spaces**) and ‘block_type’ should be a block definition object as described below. (Alternatively, StreamField can be passed a single StreamBlock instance - see Structural block types.)

**'name'** will be displayed in wagtail admin interface as the name of block.

Now I want to translate the name of blocks in StreamField.

I tried to use **gettext** and **ugettext_lazy** to wrap the **name**.

If **gettext** is used, then the display text on admin interface will be language of "**LANGUAGE_CODE**" in 'settings/base.py'. User specified language preference in admin interface will not make a difference.

If **ugettext_lazy** is used and user specified language differs from **LANGUAGE_CODE** in 'settings/base.py', there will be **keyerrors** where key is the translated content.

Is there a way to translate the name properly?

Answer (score 4):

All block types [accept a `label` argument](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#basic-block-types) for the name to display in the admin; you should apply the translation function there.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MyPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(label=_("Heading"))),
    ])
```